# returning values from all columns in a data frame after subsetting

Tags: r

This is an extension of a question I asked a few days ago titled "subset a data frame for the minimum value of a column across 20 replicates and 2 treatments", regarding the same data set but a slightly different data frame. My data frame `df` has five columns (julian date, treatment, cell, flowers, dead). there are 20 replicated cells receiving 2 treatments and flowers and dead flowers were recorded on multiple dates.

example df:

```
'juliandate' 'cell' 'treatment' 'flowers' 'dead'
260            1       1           5        0
265            1       1           8        2
270            1       1           1        5
260            1       2           1        0
265            1       2           10       2
270            1       2           0        8
260            2       1           3        0
265            2       1           9        5
270            2       1           2        12
260            2       2           2        1
265            2       2           6        2
270            2       2           3        6
```

I'm using the following code to get the julian date that corresponds to the maximum number of dead flowers for each cell within the 2 treatments, selecting the later julian date when multiple dates have the same number of dead flowers for a given cell and treatment

`df[, list(dead=max(dead), julian=max(julian[dead==max(dead)])), by=list(cell.id, treat)]`

Returning:

```
'juliandate' 'cell' 'treatment' 'dead'
270           1       1            5
270           1       2            8
270           2       1            12
270           2       2            6
```

This returns what I'm looking for, but I would also like to return the values in the flower column that correspond with this new subset.

e.g.:

```
'juliandate' 'cell' 'treatment' 'flowers 'dead'
270           1       1             1      5
270           1       2             0      8
270           2       1             2      12
270           2       2             3      6
```

Is there a nice clean way to do this without creating several subsets and merging them back together?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this is a `data.frame` and not a `data.table`? The syntax you're using doesn't look like something that would work with a `data.frame`. They are quite different objects.

Comment: yes @MrFlick, you are correct.  this example uses a `data.table`. My mistake. thanks for clarifying

Comment: @user3874999. I thought you asked for a data.table solution.

Comment: yes @akrun, I was looking for a data.table answer as that is what I am more familiar with.  However your first two offering returned incorrect numbers when I checked against the raw data.  Your third suggestion seems to be correct.  I really appreciate the help though. I can't immediately see why your first two suggestions don't work.

Comment: @user3874999, I don't see anything wrong with any of the variations. Did you test it on *this* example data? If not, do you've NAs in your data set?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Arun. Although these variations work with my simplified example, the first two variations don't seem to satisfy my originally stated goal to subset the julian date that corresponds to the maximum number of dead flowers, while selecting the later date for any dates with equal numbers of dead flowers for a given cell and treatment, when I run it with my real data.  I don't have any missing values and the third variation seems to do the trick.

Comment: I don't follow why it doesn't. Can't tell much without a reproducible example..

Comment: @Arun hmmmm...when I recreate a sample data table using the raw data that is being subset incorrectly, the code works fine. For whatever reason it doesn't work when run on my full data set.  must be something in my full data set that's tripping it up the first two variations.  I'll continue to try and figure it out.  Many thanks to you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr` works with `data.frame`s and `data.table`s (at least for some operations but it doesn't provide a kind of subsitute for all existing `data.table` operations) so in this case it should work for your data regardless of the type:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%     # data.frame or data.table 
  group_by(cell, treatment) %>%
  filter(dead == max(dead), juliandate == max(juliandate[dead==max(dead)]))

#Source: local data table [4 x 5]
#Groups: cell, treatment
#
#  juliandate cell treatment flowers dead
#1        270    1         1       1    5
#2        270    1         2       0    8
#3        270    2         1       2   12
#4        270    2         2       3    6
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some variations using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
subset(df, df[, dead == max(dead) & 
                juliandate == max(juliandate[dead == max(dead)]), 
by=list(cell, treatment)]$V1)
#    juliandate cell treatment flowers dead
# 1:        270    1         1       1    5
# 2:        270    1         2       0    8
# 3:        270    2         1       2   12
# 4:        270    2         2       3    6
```

Or

```
df[df[, dead == max(dead) &
        juliandate == max(juliandate[dead == max(dead)]), 
by=list(cell, treatment)]$V1]
```

Or

```
df[, .SD[dead == max(dead) & 
         juliandate == max(juliandate[dead==max(dead)])], 
by=list(cell, treatment)]
```

---

Also, you can use a temporary variable on all these solutions so as to avoid doing the `==` vector scan twice for each group as follows (shown here on only one variation):

```
subset(df, df[, { tmp = dead == max(dead); 
                  tmp & juliandate == max(juliandate[tmp])
                }, 
by=list(cell, treatment)]$V1)
```

Comment: @Arun, thanks. I couldn't get the tmp syntax correct.  Could you please edit the solution.

Comment: thanks @akrun, I appreciate the help.  Only the third variation seems to return the correct values though. I'm just learning so I'm not sure why this is the case.